# Colons render as periods in custom thesis class

Tags: document-classes, rendering

I'm currently writing my thesis and my university has provided me with a custom class that they have written. Everything is working fine, except that a colons '**:**' placed anywhere will only render as a period '**.**'. The only workaround I've found is to render the colon in math mode like `$:$`. Do any of you know what could cause this?

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the error. I should mention that I use *Overleaf* with *pdfLaTeX* as my compiler.

```latex
\documentclass{template/cslthse-msc}

\begin{document}
I'm a colon : \\
I'm a semicolon ;
\end{document}
```

Producing the result:

[image]

Below I've attached the class file.

```latex
% cslthse-msc.cls
% Copyright 2013 Flavius Gruian <flavius.gruian@cs.lth.se>
% 
% Licensed under the GNU GPL version 3.0 or later.
% See http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{cslthse-msc}
        [2019/10/30 v1.5 
        Masters Thesis Class, Department of Computer Science, Lund University]

%\ExecuteOptions{12pt,a4paper,onecolumn, twoside, openright}
%\ProcessOptions\relax
%\LoadClass{report}
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,twoside,openright]{report}

% margins
% use showframe in parameters if you want to check the margins
\RequirePackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}


%\usepackage{minted}


% Fonts! needs XeTeX
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\makeatletter
% for textbullets
\usepackage{textcomp}
% other useful packages
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{textpos}
% for printing used files, as a debug option
\usepackage{xparse,longtable,array}
%\usepackage{xparse,l3regex,longtable,array}
\usepackage{expl3}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@l3regex.sty\endcsname{} 


   \ifxetex
        \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
        \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%       \setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} 
%       \setsansfont{Frutiger LT Std} 
       \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
%       \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
        \setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
    \else
        \ClassWarning{cslthse-msc}{Use XeTeX for better fonts!}     
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%       \usepackage{qtxmath}    
%       \usepackage{tgtermes}
%       \usepackage{tgheros}
%       \usepackage{tgcursor}
%%% change
        \usepackage{lmodern}%\usepackage{tgcursor}
        \usepackage{qtxmath}    
%        \usepackage{tgschola}%\usepackage{tgadventor}%\usepackage{tgheros}
%        \global\let\bfseries\sbweight
        \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}%\usepackage{tgtermes} 
%        %for CormorantGaramond
        \let\oldnormalfont\normalfont
        \def\normalfont{\oldnormalfont\mdseries}
%        %endfor CormorantGaramond
%%% end change


%       \InputIfFileExists{garamond.sty}{\AtBeginDocument{\garamond}}{%
%           \ClassError{cslthse-msc}{Missing garamond.sty. Unpack the zip from http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/garamond/index.html in your source directory.}{}}
    
            
    \fi
\makeatother


% LTH color definitions - could take them out in the class
\definecolor{LTHblue}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\definecolor{LTHbronze}{RGB}{156,97,20}

% the following have also their 50% lighter versions: use \color{LTHpink!50}
\definecolor{LTHgreen}{RGB}{173,202,184}
\definecolor{LTHpink}{RGB}{233,196,199}
\definecolor{LTHcream}{RGB}{214,210,196}
\definecolor{LTHcyan}{RGB}{185,211,220}
\definecolor{LTHgrey}{RGB}{191,184,175}

% ---- Setup minted -------------

% \usemintedstyle{colorful}
% \setminted{
%     baselinestretch=1.2, % line spacing
%     bgcolor=verylightgray,
%     fontsize=\footnotesize,
%     linenos % enable line numbers
% }

% fancy headers, footers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize{\textsc{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{\textsc{\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\makeatother

% Title page
\RequirePackage{titling}

\makeatletter

% for listing packages
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfilelist}{}
 {
  \cleardoublepage
  \section*{Used ~ packages}
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{longtable}{@{} >{\ttfamily}l >{\raggedright}p{.6\textwidth} @{}}
  \nobbz_print_filelist:
  \end{longtable}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_filelist:
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { @filelist }
   {
    \nobbz_print_fileinfo:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl
 }
 
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_fileinfo:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnT { \.(sty|cls)\Z } { #1 }
   {
    \nobbz_print_pkginfo:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_pkginfo:n #1
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl
   {
    \exp_not:n { #1 }
    &
    \exp_not:v { ver@#1 }   
    \exp_not:N \tabularnewline
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%

\DeclareOption{nofilelist}{\renewcommand{\printfilelist}{}}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{cslthse-msc}{Unknown ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax


    % custom commands
    \newcommand{\company}[1]{\def \@company {#1}}
    \newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\def \@supervisor {#1}}
    \newcommand{\supervisors}[2]{\def \@firstsupervisor {#1}  \def \@secondsupervisor {#2}}
    \newcommand{\examiner}[1]{\def \@examiner {#1}}
    \newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
            \def \@subtitle {#1}
    }
%   \newcommand{\student}[1]{\def \@student {#1} \def \@author {#1}}
%   \newcommand{\student}[2]{\def \@student {#1} \def \@studentemail {#2} \def \@author {#1 \\ {\normalsize \href{mailto:#2}{\texttt{#2}}}}}
    \newcommand{\student}[2]{\def \@student {#1} \def \@studentemail {#2}}
    \newcommand{\students}[4]{\def \@firststudent {#1} \def \@firststudentemail {#2} \def \@secondstudent {#3} \def \@secondstudentemail {#4}}
    
\newcommand{\studentnames}{
\ifx\@secondstudent\empty%
                    \@student
\else%
                    \@firststudent, \@secondstudent
\fi%
}

% \def \@author {{{#1} \\ {\normalsize \href{mailto:{#2}}{\texttt{{#2}}}}}}}% \and {{#3} \\ {\normalsize \href{mailto:#4}{\texttt{#4}}}}}}      
%   \newcommand{\students}[2]{\def \@firststudent {#1} \def \@secondstudent {#2} \def \@author {#1 \and #2}}
    \newcommand{\thesisnumber}[1]{\def \@thesisnumber {#1}}
    \newcommand{\thesistype}[2]{\def \@thesistype {#1} \def \@arbete {#2}}
    \newcommand{\titlebox}[2]{\def \@titleY {#1} \def \@titleH {#2}}
    \newcommand{\onelinetitle}{\titlebox{77}{12}}
    \newcommand{\twolinestitle}{\titlebox{74}{15}}% two lines title
    \newcommand{\threelinestitle}{\titlebox{71}{18}}% three lines title
    \newcommand{\fourlinestitle}{\titlebox{68}{21}}% four lines title



    \company{}
    \supervisor{}
    \supervisors{}{}
    \examiner{}
    \subtitle{}
    \student{}{}
    \students{}{}{}{}   
    \thesistype{Master}{Examensarbete}
    % for the title page
    \pretitle{  
\ifx\@secondstudent\empty%
    \author{\@student \\ {\normalsize \href{mailto:\@studentemail}{\texttt{\@studentemail}}}}%
\else%
    \author{\@firststudent \\ {\normalsize \href{mailto:\@firststudentemail}{\texttt{\@firststudentemail}}} \and%
\@secondstudent \\ {\normalsize \href{mailto:\@secondstudentemail}{\texttt{\@secondstudentemail}}}}%
\fi%
%
% figure out title box size
%\setcounter{titleY}{80 - 3 * \@titlelines}
%cover page
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(-3.75cm,-15.7cm)%
%   \begin{overpic}[scale=2.0]{coverjpg.pdf}
\begin{overpic}[scale=.845]{template/cover.jpg}
%   \begin{overpic}[scale=1.77]{cover.png}
        \put(15,90){\color{white}\large\bfseries\textsf{\MakeUppercase{\@thesistype}'S THESIS \the\year{}}}
%       \put(15,90){\color{white}\Large\bfseries\textsf{BACHELOR'S THESIS \the\year{}}}
%       \put(15,77){\colorbox{white}{\makebox(53,12){ % 77, 12 for single line title 
%       \put(15,74){\colorbox{white}{\makebox(53,15){ % 74, 15 for double line title, 
        \put(15,\@titleY){\colorbox{white}{\makebox(53,\@titleH){ % 71, 18 for tripple line title, 
            \begin{minipage}{0.72\textwidth}
                \color{LTHbronze}
                \begin{flushleft}
%                   {\Huge\bfseries\thetitle\ } \\
                    {\fontsize{34}{40}\selectfont\bfseries\thetitle\par}
                        \vhrulefill{2pt} \\
                    \vspace{10pt}
                    {\Large\bfseries \studentnames}             
                \end{flushleft}
            \end{minipage}
        }}}
        \put(1,9){\color{white}{
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright}
                {\textsf{\textsc{ISSN 1650-2884}}}\\
                \vspace{5pt}
                {\textsf{\textsc{\@thesisnumber}}} \\ % Define thesis number in the main report file using the number from Birger Swahn - tack Niklas Lundstroem
                \vspace{10pt}
                {\textsf{\MakeUppercase{Department of Computer Science}}}\\
                \vspace{5pt}
                {\textsf{\MakeUppercase{LTH $\mid$ Lund University}}}\\
            \end{flushright}
            \end{minipage}      
        }}
        % bottom white margin...
        \put(0,2){\colorbox{white}{\makebox(68,1){}}}
        % logo
%       \put(32.5,-23.8){\includegraphics[scale=1.2]{template/LUlogoNEG.png}}       
        \put(34,-28){\includegraphics[scale=1.2]{template/LUlogoRGB.png}}       
    \end{overpic}
\end{textblock*}

\clearpage
%\begingroup
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \null
  \newpage
%\endgroup

% now the archive page
\center{\Huge \MakeUppercase{\@arbete}}\\
\center{\huge Datavetenskap}
\vspace{150pt}
\center{\huge \@thesisnumber}
\vspace{50pt}
\center{\huge\bfseries\thetitle\par}
\vspace{100pt}
\center{\Large\bfseries \studentnames}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}
\null
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}   
\setcounter{page}{1}
    
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries
    
}
    \posttitle{\par \vskip 0.5em \ifx \@subtitle \empty \vskip 0em \else {\Large(\@subtitle)} \fi \end{center}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\vskip 0.5em}
    \predate{\vskip 5em \begin{center}\Large}
    \postdate{\par\vfill {\large {\@thesistype}'s thesis work carried out at 
        \ifx\@company\empty
            \ClassWarning{cslthse-msc}{Host company missing. Use \protect\company{name}. Defaulting to CS.}
            \\ the Department of Computer Science, Lund University.
        \else \@company. \fi }
          
            \vskip 1em 
            {\normalsize
            \ifx\@supervisor\empty 
               %\ClassWarning{cslthse-msc}{Empty supervisor.}
               \ifx\@firstsupervisor\empty
                  \ClassError{cslthse-msc}{Missing supervisor. Use either \protect\supervisor{name,email} or \protect\supervisors{name1,email1}{name2,email2}}{You must specify your thesis supervisor(s).}
                \else Supervisors: \@firstsupervisor ~\\ \@secondsupervisor \fi
            \else Supervisor: \@supervisor \fi
            
            Examiner: 
            \ifx\@examiner \empty
                \ClassError{cslthse-msc}{Missing examiner. Use \protect\examiner{name,email}}{You must specify your thesis examiner.}
            \else    \@examiner \fi } \end{center}}

\makeatother


% Sections and captions
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2cm}\hrulefill]
    %\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesection}{}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\makeatother


% captions for figures and tables
\RequirePackage{caption}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\bfseries}
    \setlength{\captionmargin}{2cm}
\makeatother

% takes care of the abstract and aknowledgements
\RequirePackage{abstract}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\def \@keywords {#1}}
\newcommand{\theabstract}[1]{\def \@theabstract {#1}}
\newcommand{\acknowledgements}[1]{\def \@acknowledgements {#1}}

\keywords{}
\theabstract{}
\acknowledgements{}

% indent the abstract properly
\setlength{\absrightindent}{1cm}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{1cm}

% makes everything in the begining of the document
\newcommand{\makefrontmatter}{
    \maketitle

    % make the abstract and keywords
    \ifx \@theabstract \@empty
        \ClassWarning{cslthse-msc}{The abstract is missing. Use \protect\theabstract{text}.}
    \else
        % empty page        
        \pagestyle{empty}
        % make sure the abstract is on a right-hand side
        \cleardoublepage
        \begin{abstract}
        \noindent
        \@theabstract       
        \ifx \@keywords \@empty
            \ClassWarning{cslthse-msc}{Keywords are missing. Use \protect\keywords{words}.}
        \else
            \vspace{2cm}\par\noindent {\small{\bf Keywords\/}: \@keywords}
        \fi
        \end{abstract}
    \fi
    
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    % add acknowledgement if any
    \ifx \@acknowledgements \@empty
            \relax
    \else
            \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
            \@acknowledgements
    \fi

    \tableofcontents
}   
\makeatother


% make the bibliography
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makebibliography}[1]{
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{#1}
}%
```

And here's the log file:

https://pastebin.com/TR6Sd7c1

**Update**
It seems to be a problem with the compiler. *pdfLaTeX* and *LaTeX* renders my colon as a period, while *XeLaTeX* and *LuaLaTeX* correctly renders the colon :/. However, in all other projects I have used *pdfLaTeX* without any problems...

**Update 2**
It seems to be a problem with the package *CormorantGaramond*. When I comment it out, the periods are correctly rendered, although in a not as nice font. I guess I'll have to research how to use that font with pdfLaTeX...

Comment: If I try `\documentclass{cslthse-msc}\begin{document};\end{document}` I get a semicolon. The class file has some glitches, though: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should *never* appear in such a file at the outer level. However this doesn't seem related to your problem.

Comment: @egreg I'm really sorry, I meant COLON not SEMICOLON! Semicolons do work for me too...

Comment: do the colons also fail in egreg minimal example?

Comment: @Zorobay If I change `;` into `:` I get a colon. Can you supplement your question with a sample (short) document that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @egreg Added a minimal example...

Comment: @Zorobay I get a colon anyway.

Comment: @egreg I added an update, it seems to be a problem with the compiler...

Comment: Can you add the log file?

Comment: @egreg I linked the log output...

Comment: try a small example with article as class and only \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}. Does this fail too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yup it does...

Comment: I can reproduce it on overleaf. I will take a look.

Comment: The pfb in overleaf is broken. I uploaded a pfb from my local texlive and then the colon reappeared.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer would that be a solution for me too? Could you guide me through that process? :)

Comment: you can try: copy all the files here in your project folder: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cormorantgaramond/type1, But I notified also someone from overleaf, perhaps they can update the package. You can also try to use an older texlive version on overleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer, we were able to find the culprit. It seems like the package `CormorantGaramond` is outdated on overleaf. Ulrike suggested I copy the updated `.pfb` files from here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cormorantgaramond/type1 to the root of my Overleaf project, and lo and behold, my colons are back! Hopefully the package will be updated on overleaf soon.